# Create Portal in Oracle Utilities Mobile Workforce Management 2.0.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-maf

I am using  Oracle Utilities Mobile Workforce Management 2.0.0 . I want to automate the create portal process .Is there any way by which it can be accomplished ? Is it possible to add it through back end i.e. using DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Insert entries into CI_PORTAL and CI_PORTAL_L tables